# How can I authorize more than one Dropbox account in an app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, dropbox-api

I'm looking to update one of my apps (which is a Dropbox client) to have support for multiple accounts, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I have analyzed the SDK many times and no matter how many times I look at, it looks like an account using the official SDK can only support one account at a time. Although I'm sure it can support more as I know of many apps that allow you to link more than one.

Any pointers on doing this will be highly appreciated. I can't even find a way to fetch tokens to store them separately later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this to be a challenge but finally made it work after lots of experimentation. Here are some bits of information that should help:

Each Dropbox (DB) account has a userid (uid) associated with it once the user has been authorized. In your own app's model for an account, you need to keep track of the uid. Initially, before the user links their DB account, this uid will be `nil`.

When the user wants to access their DB account, you get your associated uid for the account. If the uid isn't nil you setup the `DBRestClient` as follows:

```
_client = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession] userId:uid];
```

If the uid isn't set yet, you need to present the login screen.

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:someController];
```

This, of course, launches the DB app to present the login (or presents a web interface if the DB app isn't installed). Either way, your app will be launched again by DB when the user finishes the authorization process.

In your app delegate's `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method you do something like:

```
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    NSString *query = url.query;
    if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"cancel"].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSDictionary *urlData = [DBSession parseURLParams:query];
        NSString *uid = [urlData objectForKey:@"uid"];
        if ([[[DBSession sharedSession] userIds] containsObject:uid]) {
            // At this point we know the login succeeded and we have the newly linked userid
            // make a call to process the uid
        }
    } else {
        // user cancelled the login
    }
}
```

In the code that processes the newly linked uid, you can store the uid in your own account data model. Then you use the uid to create the `DBRestClient` like I showed earlier.

If you have a uid, you can determine if the uid is properly linked with a simple check:

```
if ([[[DBSession sharedSession] userIds] containsObject:uid]) {
    // the uid is linked
}
```

To unlink a user based on their uid you can do:

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkUserId:uid];
```

At that point I would also clear out the saved uid from your own account model.

Hopefully that is enough pieces to build the puzzle. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will give this ago and then mark your answer as chosen accordingly. So the Dropbox SDK does have native support for multiple users after all.

Comment: I have fiddled with it. Not a full implementation, but good enough to see this has a high chance of working. I need to store the ids separately, correct?

Comment: Yes, the uid you get when the user authorizes your app must be stored by your app and associated with the corresponding "account" you have in the app.

Comment: Okay cool, that was my only doubt. Thanks a lot for your time @rmaddy. I really appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @rmaddy Ever had an issue where after succesfully linking an account, and restarting the application, the Dropbox session doesn't seem to load previously linked userIds?

Comment: No, I've never had such a problem. If you are having an issue then post a question with relevant details.

Comment: Hey rmaddy, I could not make this solution work. The [DBSession sharedSession] is nil if you did not init properly with the app key and secret key. And another problem is that you need to add the proper URL scheme on the plist("db-[APP_KEY]") otherwise the SDK return you an error. Do you have a workaround for this? Best

Comment: For whoever comes next I think there is something to add to this answer because, to me, is not clear. To enable multiple account you need to use an application key and a secret key to setup the first DBSession, this to me was not clear. Once you setup your DBSession, you can then use the procedure on top to achieve multi account. I was thinking there was a way to do it without the need of app key and secret key, that bring me in the wrong direction for a while. Cheers

Comment: @EnricoBottani The answer assumed you already had everything working with one Dropbox account which of course means you need to setup the app key and secret, and the URL. You do not need to use `DBSession sharedSession`. That is optional. It's never needed even with one account.